# Creating a pop up button interface

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, button

In Apple's stock 'Messages' app, tapping the camera button reveals popup buttons allowing the user to take a photo/video or choose an existing one. How would I implemented this same button design? Is the procedure the same for both iPhone & iPad?

Answer (score 2):

It's called a `UIActionSheet`. You use it like this

```
UIActionSheet *action = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Foo" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"foo1", @"foo2", nil];
[action showInView:self.view];
```

(change the foos to whatever). To detect what button was clicked, implement the `UIActionSheetDelegate`'s `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:` delegate method. For example:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    NSString *title = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if ([title isEqualToString:@"foo1"]) {
        // do stuff...
    }
}
```

And yes, this works on both the iPhone and iPad (as @bobnoble pointed out, the iPad version uses a popover view, not an action sheet, but action sheets work on both).

Comment: On an iPad, present the `UIActionSheet` in a popover, same as done on the iPad version of Messages. On an iPhone, you likely want to add a 'Cancel' button.