# If else statement is causing me trouble

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, uiactionsheet

I have an if else if statement that is giving me trouble.

First, here's my code:

```
if([_hasUserTakenAPhoto  isEqual: @"YES"]) {

    _xButtonAfterPhotoTaken = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [_xButtonAfterPhotoTaken showInView:self.view];


    _xButtonActionSheetTitle = [_xButtonAfterPhotoTaken buttonTitleAtIndex:0];


} else if ([_xButtonActionSheetTitle isEqualToString:@"Delete"]) {


        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"backToHomeFromMediaCaptureVC" sender:self];


    } else {



    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"backToHomeFromMediaCaptureVC" sender:self];



}
```

My problem is that I need to perform the method call of:

`[_xButtonActionSheetTitle isEqualToString:@"Delete"]` and if it is equal to "Delete", then I need to perform a segue using this method call:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"backToHomeFromMediaCaptureVC" sender:self];
```

The only way I know how to do this is with another if statement, which you can see in my original code I started with "else if", but this creates different scope for all of my action sheet statements.

I just need to make the title of "Delete" on my action sheet tappable and it needs to trigger the segue.

I was trying to follow this action sheet answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17374248/3117509

I just can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: "but this creates different scope for all of my action sheet statements" -- You don't declare any variables anywhere in the above code, so how is a "different scope" a problem?

Comment: Your problem is not clear.  Please give the issue some context-- what is happening instead of what you want, etc.  My first thought is "Why are you using 'isEqual' in your first 'if' statement instead of 'isEqualToString'?"  But I don't even know if that's relevant based on your question.

Answer (score -1):

Closing question. The problem is that I do not have a solid grasp on UIActionSheets.

Comment: That is what a [delete] link is for :-)

Comment: But now it can't be deleted since it has an answer.

Comment: At least we can close it for duplicate with the other issue he posted.

Comment: Lesson learned. I will delete the thread next time. Sorry.